# How can I exclude IDs with a React admin ReferenceInput filter?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

While using ReferenceInput we can use a filter like this.

```
<ReferenceInput source="company_id" reference="companies"  filter={{ ids: [1, 2, 3}} >
    <AutocompleteInput label="Employer" />
</ReferenceInput>
```

This will return companies with id 1, 2 or 3 in the AutoComplete Input

However, my requirement is to filter to exclude some IDs e.g.(ids not in [1, 2, 3]). I'm not sure how can I use such filter here.

Comment: What are your exclusion specifications? Your question isn't very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rule for applying operators in filters in react-admin (see https://marmelab.com/react-admin/FilteringTutorial.html#filter-operators for details). The filter is passed to `dataProvider.getList()`, so it is is your dataProvider's responsibility to handle these operators.

You could e.g. set a filter named `ids_not_in`in your input:

```
<ReferenceInput source="company_id" reference="companies"  filter={{ ids_not_in: [1, 2, 3}} >
    <AutocompleteInput label="Employer" />
</ReferenceInput>
```

Then, in your dataProvider, translate that filter to operators that your API can understand.